# AngularJS route without slash

Tags: javascript, angularjs, slash, angularjs-routing

in AngularJS can I set up a style route like this:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/title-and-more-irrelevant-text-123456-category.html
```

where '123546' is an indentifier  ?

with:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

I must make this because I need keep the old URLs

Comment: Can you explain your scenario a bit more? This is too rudimentary.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the entire path, then I guess it will be hard because it is too generic.

If however you can live with paths in the form `/prefix/title-and-stuff-123456-foo.html` (i.e. the entire URL would look like `http://mysrv.com/ctx/#/prefix/title-and-stuff-123.html`), read on.

You can define the route as: `/prefix/*titleAndId`. Notice the `*`. Then the entire string is accessible inside any controller as `$route.current.params.titleAndId`. You can parse this string (using an appropriate regular expression perhaps) and extract any information, then load the appropriate content.

The `*` in the route definition enables the argument to contain slashes too. If slashes are not required, you can use `/prefix/:titleAndId` and use it the same way.

Comment: thanks, ¿Can't I separate the identifier, 'category' in the URL with distinct $route.current.params?

Comment: @aloon I don't think it is possible.